# Able to print only some objects in ArrayList by overwriting toString()

Tags: java, oop, object, arraylist, tostring

I have some problems of printing out the object after overwriting toString(). Without overwriting toString(), I can print out the object references without any error. However when I try to overwrite the toString() method, I can print out some output(~10 out of 30 outputs) only while some others give error.

The error is:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
        at Airline.toString(AirlineMain.java:277)
        at java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:2902)
        at java.io.PrintStream.println(PrintStream.java:821)
        at AirlineMain.main(AirlineMain.java:432)
```

Basically I have a class named "Airline" and objects are being created and stored into `ArrayList<Airline>`.

The Airline class constructor:

```
public Airline(String fromCity, String toCity, SGTime departTime,
             int arriveDay, SGTime arriveTime, int cost) {
         this.fromCity = fromCity;
         this.toCity = toCity;
         this.departTime = departTime;
         this.arriveDay = arriveDay;
         this.arriveTime = arriveTime;
         this.cost = cost;

     }
```

The SGTime constructor:

```
public SGTime(int hour, int min) {
          this.hour = hour;
          this.min = min;
      }
```

My overwriting of toString():

```
public String toString() {
return getFromCity() +" "+ getToCity()+" "+getDepartTime().getHour()+":"+getDepartTime().getMin()+" "+getArriveDay()+" "+getArriveTime().getHour()+":"+getArriveTime().getMin()+" "+getCost();
}
```

All the instance attributes have the accessor being defined. Example:

```
public String getFromCity (){
         return fromCity;
}
```

Thanks in advance for any guidance!

Answer (score 3):

In

```
return getFromCity() +" "+ 
  getToCity()+" "+
  getDepartTime().getHour()+":"+
  getDepartTime().getMin()+" "+
  getArriveDay()+" "+
  getArriveTime().getHour()+":"+
  getArriveTime().getMin()+" "+
  getCost();
```

The only possible causes of NPE are if `getDepartTime()` or `getArriveTime()` return null.

If any of the other methods return null, then by JLS 15.18.1.1 they are converted to the literal string `"null"`.  For `getDepartTime` and `getArriveTime` you are attempting to invoke a method, and if the reference returned is null an NPE will be thrown.

Comment: Thanks for the prompt reply! Your advise has narrow down in finding the problems.

Answer (score 1):

Do not re-invent wheel. I would recommend you use a well known library like `apache-commons ToStringBuilder` http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.5/org/apache/commons/lang/builder/ToStringBuilder.html . If you are using `toString()` for debugging purposes then you can look at its subclass `ReflectionToStringBuilder` too. It will take care of requirement with a few lines of code something like:

```
@Override
toString() {
    if(!DEBUG_ON) {
       return super.toString();            
    }
     return ReflectionToStringBuilder.toString(this);
}
```

EDIT: refelction (on deep object graph) is a slow operation and you should use this with caution. For debugging purpose (in test envireonment) or one-off use it is OK.